# php include prohibitions

Tags: php, include

I am trying to include a file in an included file  The point where I want to include it is within a switch statement.  For some reason it is not working and it is driving me crazy.  As far as I know there is no bar to an include within an include or placing an include within braces.  The specific error I am getting is

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_INCLUDE, expecting T_CASE or T_DEFAULT or '}' i
```

Can anyone spot error is there some prohibition on this?

First file.

```
<?php include("includes/getdata.php"); ?>
```

First included file

```
<?php
//some code
switch ($action)
{
?>
<?php include("words.php"); ?>
<?php
}
//rest of code
?>
```

Include within include (words.php)

```
<?php
case 'research':
$word = "web";
break;
//various other cases

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just read the error message again.

```
switch (...) {
    include ...
}
```

This is invalid. You need a `case` or `default` keyword before any other code in a `switch` statement:

```
switch (...) {
    case ... :
        include ...
}
```

What you're trying to do doesn't work and is a bad idea to begin with.

Comment: ok.  So you cannot place an include immediately after the brace of a switch statement?  The reason I'm not putting the whole switch statement in the include is that the var name is different in different pages calling it.  The blocks are to see the include more easily in the code.

Comment: You cannot place *any* code inbetween a `switch` without `case` or `default`. What would you expect this to do? Code inside a `switch` is only executed when the `case` matches. Code without `case` inside `switch` has no defined meaning. `include` is no exception. The way you're trying to cobble that code together is a bad idea. Use functions or something else that's self-contained and reusable, don't combine several code fragments across several files.

Comment: ok.  I guess I will have to make varnames match in different source files and put whole switch statement in include.  Thanks

Comment: I think I would rather use same varnames than pass different ones through function...

Comment: Whatever floats your boat. If you like big ball of mud spaghetti code, go on.

Comment: wow that was obnoxious.  Glad I did not mark your question correct!  What a loser you are.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. I'm trying to point you in the direction of sane programming practices, which you appear to be lacking. **For your own benefit!** Nice being called a "loser" for that.

Answer (score 0):

wrong syntax of [switch case](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

```
switch(expression)
{
  case 'some value' : //you code; break;
  default: // default code
}
```

so you must need to add `default: include_once 'word.php'`

Comment: syntax worked before I took cases out and put them in include...will recheck.  BTW, I am doing this because the cases are common to multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you consistently opening and closing PHP blocks?

```
//some code
switch ($action) {
    include("words.php");
}
//rest of code
```

This is wrong because you've not stated a case for the action.

```
//some code
switch ($action) {
    case 'A': // This is mandatory
      include("words.php");
      break;
}
//rest of code
```